# JavaScript to select only text in page

Tags: javascript

How to use JavaScript to select only all texts in a page, including all elements in `<body></body>`

My question is based on another existing question here 
https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Hcx6H/

in the jsfiddle as you can see if text is Arabic, then direction will be changed accordingly. but it will select only text between `

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>ظغعظ</div>
```

> How to use that java script to select all texts inside body including all elements ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var te=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
 console.log(te.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""));
```

Comment: First line selects all html between the body tag as HTML and the second line strips the html tags and finally you get only text

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery, you can use `$("body").text()` (cf http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: jQuery isn't a tag in this question.

Answer (score -1):

using jQuery you can very easily achieve that

```
<body>
<div>hello</div>
<div>ظغعظ</div>
</body>
```

In javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   // This give return only texts inside the body tags
   console.log($("body").text());
    })
  </script>
```